# How to refer child class attributes in the parent class docstring?

Tags: python, parent-child, python-sphinx, docstring, cross-reference

I'm using `:inherited-members:` to show parent methods.

In the documentation generated for the child, is it possible to refer to the child class?

```
class Parent:
   """This is a {Child class name} class

   This is in the {Child group attribute} group
   """
   group = ''
   ...

class Child(Parent):
   group = 'TheChild'
   ...
```

In the generated documentation for the child, I would like to see:

```
> class Child(Parent)
>   Bases: Parent
>   This is a Child class.
>   It is in the TheChild group
```

Is this possible with Sphinx?

Comment: What is `group` (or  `TheChild` group) in this case? Is it the group of children? Is it a group you define? Is it the docstring of the Child class?

Comment: group is just a class attribute.  I could have just as easily called it `xyz`.  Each child will override the group attribute with their own value.  Does that help?

Comment: Even if you could, it'd make for a confusing docstring.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica if you know how to read Python Sphinx it's not confusing. Besides, the object names are fully qualified. You can opt for documenting in the docstring or the rst files, that choice is at the each devs discretion. Unless you produce a PEP that recommends otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Sphinx [Cross-referencing syntax](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html?highlight=cross#cross-referencing-syntax) inside the docstrings, with the appropriate [roles](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#cross-referencing-python-objects) from the [Python domain](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html?highlight=cross#the-python-domain). After that the [autodoc directives](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directives) in your `.rst` take care of the rest.

Example parent_child.py

```py
class Parent:
    """
    This is a :py:class:`Child` class.

    This is in the :py:data:`Child.group` attribute.
    """
    group = 'TheParent'


class Child(Parent):
    group = 'TheChild'
```

parent_child.rst

```
Parent\_Child
=============

.. autoclass:: parent_child.Parent
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:

.. autoclass:: parent_child.Child
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

And the result:

[image: parent_child_image]

Comment: They wanted the `Child` stuff to show up in the `Child` documentation, not the parent.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica [Python documentation has examples otherwise](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.is_reserved). Raise your objections with the core devs.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. The fact that some particular class in the standard library was documented one way doesn't change how the question is asking for its documentation to be generated. Plus, what you're doing doesn't even match the stdlib documentation you linked.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica the OP thinks otherwise, the official documentation gives an example otherwise, (I don't have to explain anything to you, the question wasn't clear -you still don't understand it- and if the OP had clarified differently I would have adapted the solution.)